# Need help on nested Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am working on DRF first time and got stuck at one place. This is just a hypothetical example related to issue I am facing:

## models.py

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    manufacturer_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        Manufacturer, related_name='manufacturerCars', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    car_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

## Serializers.py

```
class ManufacturerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Manufacturer
        fields = ("manufacturer_id", "manufacturer_name", "manufacturerCars",)


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ("car_id", "manufacturer")
```

When I access /api/cars/ endpoint, I get all the details about car including it's manufacturer:

```
car_details = [
{
    "car_id": "1",
    "car_name": "abc",        
    "manufacturer": {
        "manufacturer_id": "1",
        "manufacturer_name": "XYZ",
        "manufacturerCars": [
            "1",
            "7",
            "3",
            "5"
        ]
    }
}
```

]

## Question:

What approach should I take to list all the cars associated with current car's manufacturer -manufacturerCars field in above output- (i.e. details about cars with id 1, 7, 3, 5) ? Do I need to iterate over all the data that I got from /api/cars ?

Highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new serializer for car model.

```
class AnotherCarSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ("car_id",)

class ManufacturerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manufacturerCars = AnotherCarSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Manufacturer
        fields = ("manufacturer_id", "manufacturer_name", "manufacturerCars",)


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ("car_id", "manufacturer")
```